# unzip multiple files with nodejs and StreamZip

Tags: node.js, typescript

i am trying to unzip multiple files using NodeJs and StreamZip. this is what i am trying:

```
export const unpackZip = async (folder: string) => {

  const zipPath = await getFilesByExtension(folder, ".zip").then((zipFile)=>{console.log("ZIPFILE", zipFile)
  return zipFile})
  console.log("DEBUG PATH: ", zipPath)
  let zip: StreamZip
  await Promise.all(zipPath.map((zipFile) => {
    return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
      zip = new StreamZip({ storeEntries: true, file: `${folder}/${zipFile}` });
      zip.on('error', function (err) { console.error('[ERROR]', err); });
      zip.on('ready', function () {
        console.log('All entries read: ' + zip.entriesCount);
        console.log(zip.entries());
      });
      zip.on('entry', function (entry) {
        const pathname = path.resolve('./tmp', entry.name);
        if (/\.\./.test(path.relative('./tmp', pathname))) {
          console.warn("[zip warn]: ignoring maliciously crafted paths in zip file:", entry.name);
          return;
        }
        if ('/' === entry.name[entry.name.length - 1]) {
          console.log('[DIR]', entry.name);
          return;
        }
        zip.extract(entry, `tmp/${entry.name}`, (err?: string, res?: number | undefined) => {
          resolve(entry.name)
        })
      })
    })
  }))

};
```

the problem is, that it does indeed go through all the zip files in the folder (getFilesByExtension returns an array of filename strings like `[asdf.zip, asdf1.zip, ... ]`)
but the actual filecontent from all unpacked zips is from the first zip. a Screenshot may say more than i can:

[image: unzp problem]

can someone spot the problem in the code?! i am kind of clueless where the issue could be :/

any help would be awesome!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind... i cannot use map here - if i use a for loop and await my new Promise it works:

```
  for (const zipFile of zipPath) {
     await new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
      zip = new StreamZip({ storeEntries: true, file: `${folder}/${zipFile}` });
      zip.on('error', function (err) { console.error('[ERROR]', err); });
      zip.on('ready', function () {
        console.log('All entries read: ' + zip.entriesCount);
        console.log(zip.entries());
      });
      zip.on('entry', function (entry) {
        const pathname = path.resolve('./tmp', entry.name);
        if (/\.\./.test(path.relative('./tmp', pathname))) {
          console.warn("[zip warn]: ignoring maliciously crafted paths in zip file:", entry.name);
          return;
        }
        if ('/' === entry.name[entry.name.length - 1]) {
          console.log('[DIR]', entry.name);
          return;
        }
        zip.extract(entry, `tmp/${entry.name}`, (err?: string, res?: number | undefined) => {
          resolve(entry.name)
        })
      })
    })
  }
```